# MySql convert long date format string (e.g. 20th-March-2001) to date YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I am trying to convert long date format string (e.g. 1st-June-1999 or  20th-March-2001) to date YYYY-MM-DD using MySql 5.7.

Reading docs tried to use `STR_TO_DATE`:

```
select STR_TO_DATE(dob,'%d-%M-YYYY') from table
```

However, this returns `null` due to the day suffix (e.g. `th`).

I could use update query with `REPLACE()` to remove the suffix and then `STR_TO_DATE`, but is there a better solution?

Comment: What format do you have for March 21: 21th-March-2001, or 21st-March-2001?

Comment: 01st-March-2001 or 1st-March-2001?

Comment: all dates are in long string format e.g. 20th-March-2001 or 1st-June-1999

Comment: `%d` should be `%D`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%D` does what you want:

```
str_to_date(dob, '%D-%M-%Y')
```

Comment: Why not delete the rest of the answer

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems. First, you need `%D` (capital not lowercase) since you have the suffix after the day of the month.
Next, the year should simply be `%Y`.

So, the select statement would be

`select STR_TO_DATE(dob,'%D-%M-%Y') from table;`

w3schools has a good reference for the abbreviations: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp